# Sorted function using compare function

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I'd like to sort a 2D list where each "row" is of size 2, like that for example

```
[[2,5],[2,3],[10,11]]
```

These rows represent ranges in fact, so Its always [a,b] where a <= b

I want to sort it exactly this way, each element of the list being a 2-list, I'd have (by order of priority):
[a1, b1] compared to [a2, b2]

```
 1. If a1 < a2 do not permute
 2. If a1 > a2 permute
 3. If a1 == a2 then permute if (b1 - a1) > (b2 - a2)
```

What I find kind of stupid is that python doesnt allow anymore for comparison functions. Instead it uses a key function. Theres no way I can make a valid key with that as I base my comparison on two parameters, the numeric value of 'a' (which prevails) and then length of the range (b - a).

How can I sort this? I mean, without calling two times sorted() or something, which in my opinion is plain ugly.

Is it even possible? Or is there something I don't see?

Thanks!

Comment: When invoking sorted(elements, cmp=func) on python 3.3.3 it gives me "'cmp' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) offer a `cmp` to `key` conversion function but it is not all that pretty.

Comment: You can also create a class for inner list and override [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are cases that can't be handled by a `key`. This is not one of them. The solution is to make the key function return a `tuple`

```
>>> L = [[2, 5], [2, 3], [10, 11]]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1] - x[0]))
[[2, 3], [2, 5], [10, 11]]
```

Comment: I am curious about cases that can not be solved using `key`. Do you have some example, please?

Comment: Much thanks! I second @Delgan, would be nice to know which cases cannot be solved (I wasnt aware tuples was a working solution)

Comment: @Delgan, Suppose the sublists list were `[firstname, surname]` I need to sort by surname. Where the surnames are equal I need to sort by firstname - but in reverse.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy `key=lambda x:(x[1], [-ord(i) for i in x[0]])` should work, am I wrong? However, this is probably not great, I wonder what is the proper way for solving this issue.